# Show a span on hover of parent and hide it with delay using only CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I need to show a `span` on hover of link and hide it on mouseout after 2 seconds. Below is the code what I have done. This can be done using JS. However, I need **CSS only solution**.

The current speed to show the span is perfect. I just need to hide it on mouseout after 2 seconds.

```css
.hoverBox span {
  opacity: 0;  
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.hoverBox:hover span {
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverBox">Mouse hover <span>Hello</span></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the third parameter to transition

```css
.hoverBox span {
  opacity: 0;  
  transition: opacity 0.5s 1s;
}
.hoverBox:hover span {
  opacity: 1;  
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverBox">Mouse hover <span>Hello</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can get this behavior easily with a CSS animation. The `2s` animation play time happens after the `0.5s` opacity transition, so if you want the whole thing to be two seconds, you can change the animation time to `1.5s`.

```css
.hoverBox span {
    opacity: 0;  
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.hoverBox:hover span {
    opacity: 1;  
    animation: glimpse 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* This is to make it only play once */
}
@keyframes glimpse {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    99% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverBox">Mouse hover <span>Hello</span></div>
```

Comment: This isn't I am looking for. It should hide on mouse out after 2s. Anyways Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Tushar Ah, well that's pertinent info :-P In that case even a transition adjustment would work like Matej's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transition-delay` to make it disappear after 2s:

```
.hoverBox span {
  opacity: 0;  
  transition: opacity 0.5s; // or transition:opacity 0.5s 2s; the 3rd param is the delay.
  transition-delay:2s;
}
.hoverBox:hover span {
  opacity: 1;  
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bk9vnubx/